# Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found when i used kartik-v/yii2-mpdf, installed without Composer

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

I added 5 folders to the vendor folder:

- paragonie
- setasign
- psr/log
- mpdf
- kartik-v/yii2-mpdf

Then I wrote in the vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php:

```
'Mpdf\\' => array($vendorDir . '/mpdf/mpdf/src'),
'kartik\\mpdf\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src'),
```

And wrote in the vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php:

```
    'kartik-v/yii2-mpdf' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'kartik-v/yii2-mpdf',
    'version' => '9999999-dev',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@kartik/mpdf' => $vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src',
    ),
  ),
```

When I call in the controller:

```
$pdf = new Pdf();
```

I get an error:

[image: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found]

Previously, when I manually added an extension, there were no problems.

Comment: Why would you manually try to piece together composer packages?

Comment: I can't download via Composer, because composer.json was not updated for a long time, and extensions were added manually

Comment: When installing a package, use the `composer require <author>/<package>`. Alternatively, you can alter your composer.json file and add the packages into the `require` key and then run `composer dump-autoload`; but please don't _manually_ add packages.

Comment: It sounds like you want to update some of your packages, but the versions are restricting you. Read this documentation on how to uplift your package versions. https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md Maybe you can upload your composer.json to the question and we can have a look at the dependencies and version restrictions.